# VBA Remove duplicates function consistently returning run-time 1004 error

Tags: excel, vba

Im trying to execute a simple remove duplicates function.
My vba code is just the following:

```
Range("F:G").Select
Selection.RemoveDuplicates Columns:=1, Header:=xlYes
```

My data is basic and looks something like this:

[image: data]

however I keep receiving the 1004 runtime error (application or object defined error). I've tried quite a number of code variants to do this, but none of them worked.
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I've tried working with an array as well as selecting the specific range and not the entire column, which also didnt work.

Comment: This error can occur if you have merged cells in a range

Comment: this is not the case

Comment: Your code should work as it is. Do you have any merge cells, sheet protection etc.?